# Template are always fragment

Tags: vue.js, brunch

I'm using Vue and Brunch in a small project, today I decide to add Vueify to make my components more concise.

But they are always seen has fragment instance so they are not rendered.

```
<template lang="pug">
    div.sticker-container.sticker-xs-container.nav-top-sticker-animate#btn-about(v-bind:href="link")
        span.sticker.sticker-xs.sticker-dark
            span.sticker-txt.sticker-xs-txt(v-html="locales.btns.open")
        span.sticker.sticker-xs.sticker-over.sticker-over-xs.sticker-light(v-show="opened")
        span.sticker-txt.sticker-xs-txt.sticker-light-txt(v-html="locales.btns.close")
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
     return {
        disabled: false,
        link: '#'
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

To use Vueify I simply add Vue-brunch to my project and I call this vue component like this:

```
import bar from './foo/bar'
Vue.component('sticker-bar', bar)
```

So, what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a surrounding div within your template. Like so:

```
<template>
   <div>
       <content></content>
    </div>
</template>
```

Most times this will solve the fragment instance error.

For more detailed info: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Fragment-Instance

I hope it helps!

Comment: My template is already contained in a div, I need another one ? :o

Comment: 9 out of 10 times I had this error by placing a div around my content within the template. So it's worth a try.

Comment: Is your example complete,did you leave anything out? E.g. a `v-for` or `v-if` on the root element also makes it a fragment instance, because there is no reliable root element.

Otherwise, it seems fine, so to analyse further we would need an example that acually reproduces this error.